# Scene rendering from pivot point of an object

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, scene, origin

I'm pretty new to  render and got an issue when I tried to render this scene because the active camera switches to another wiew from an origin point of another object (Plane.001) there are no other cameras and the active camera is an fspy camera because i used a photo reference and it's an easy program to use but this issue might be becouse of the program.

I also triedd to add another camera and use that camera but it always render from the same origin point and there aren't other cameras in the scene

**I have no idea of how to fix this please help**

[image: dimostration]

this is what i see when i try to render whit the right camera active

[image: [![this is what i see when i try to render whit the right camera]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue too and I fixed it by duplicating the mesh the camera was attaching to and then deleting the original mesh while leaving the copy in place.

Comment: thanks a lot you really saved me i was going to discard this scene until i got an answer :)